# Trouble understanding how to map/convert JSON to Java Object

Tags: java, android, json, api, gson

Hello :D I'm trying to get a JSON string from an API (openweathermap.org) I've done the api call and I've gotten the string and even used the gson library to make it into a 'pretty' json format but I don't understand how I'd map those values from the string, into separate and accessible values.

I am coding in Java in the Android Studio IDE :)

This is how the raw JSON string looks:
{"coord":{"lon":50,"lat":50},"list":[{"main":{"aqi":1},"components":{"co":267.03,"no":0,"no2":0.47,"o3":76.53,"so2":1.65,"pm2_5":0.87,"pm10":3.09,"nh3":0.07},"dt":1640437200}]}

I have a separete class called airPollution which I will initialize the values such as
private String coord etc but I can't seem to figure out the complexity of the JSON string,
would coord be a list with the keys lon and lat? Same for the list part of the JSON.

Here is the current code, it is not much: I've commented out the things I was trying to fiddle around with, please let me know if anything isn't clear. Any pointers are appreciated, just trying to wrap my head around it :) I've also used jsonviewer.stack.hu which helped a little bit but I still don't know how I'd structure the lists.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/air_pollution?lat=50&lon=50&appid=0140f9110ece5d6477b5ac95aba2020d";

        //create a request queue

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // construct request
        //you can use json array or json object request or string request

        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.e("Reponse", response.toString());
                        String json = response.toString();
                        JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
                        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create(); // pretty print
                        String prettyJson = gson.toJson(json);
                        System.out.println(prettyJson);

                        //JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
                        //Assert.assertTrue(jsonObject.isJsonObject());
                        //Assert.assertTrue(convertedObject.isJsonObject());
                        
               //Assert.assertTrue(convertedObject.get("coord").getAsString().equals("lon"));
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Reponse", error.toString());
                    }
                }

        );
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

}
```

airPollution class (not how it would be at all just a general idea of what I'm supposed to be doing?)

```
public class airPollution {


    private String coord;
    private String lon;
    private String lat;

    public String getCoord() {
        return coord;
    }

    public void setCoord(String coord) {
        this.coord = coord;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to pass the `class` which to expect, else it won't know what it is:

```
AirPollution convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, AirPollutionResponse.class);
```

While `class AirPollution` may or may not require further code annotations... depending if the field names match the input JSON field names. On Android model classes may often have lots of annotations, eg. when using them with Retrofit (which internally uses GSON) and Room.

Also see the GSON [user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

---

That model class doesn't match the input JSON the least ...as the reading comes with an envelope.

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 50,
        "lat": 50
    },
    "list": [{
        "main":{
            "aqi": 1
        },
        "components":{
            "co": 267.03,
            "no": 0,
            "no2": 0.47,
            "o3": 76.53,
            "so2": 1.65,
            "pm2_5": 0.87,
            "pm10": 3.09,
            "nh3": 0.07
        },
        "dt": 1640437200
    }]
}
```

And the now deleted answer wasn't that wrong, because this requires 5!! Java classes to map.

Class `AirPollution`:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class AirPollution {

    @SerializedName("co")
    private Double carbonMonoxide = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("no")
    private Double nitricOxide = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("no2")
    private Double nitrogenDioxide = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("o3")
    private Double ozone = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("so2")
    private Double sulfurDioxide = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("pm2_5")
    private Double particulateMatterTwoFive = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("pm10")
    private Double particulateMatterTen = 0.0;

    @SerializedName("nh3")
    private Double ammonia = 0.0;
    ...
}
```

Wrapped with `class List` (which isn't really a list):

```
public class List {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    private int timestamp = 0;    

    @SerializedName("components")
    private AirPollution reading = null;
    ...
}
```

Wrapped with `class AirPollutionResponse`:

```
public class AirPollutionResponse {

    @SerializedName("list")
    private List list = null;
    ...
}
```

Further fields on `AirPollution` (alike `dt`, `lat`, `lng`) would need to be manually set.
Despite it's possible to map nested classes, a class can only be mapped one-dimensional.
One still can add getters for nested values, when the nesting gets too extreme.

Comment: Not familiar with this API, but can you skip the middleman `JsonObject`? e.g. `Response.Listener<AirPollution>`

Comment: Java / Retrofit is more sophisticated than that; eg. `Call<AirPollutionResponse> api`, `Callback<AirPollutionResponse> callback`, `Call<AirPollutionResponse> call`, `Response<AirPollutionResponse> response` ...where `AirPollutionResponse` should wrap eg. `ArrayList<AirPollution> data`, as transfer envelope. Even with only 1 item, it's generally desired to have some kind of standard message envelope.

Comment: Thank you, its what I've currently been trying to wrap my head around, I tried to use jsonschema2pojo but I think that made me even more confused as I wasn't understanding it, if I could upvote you I would!! <3